# github commit information: A commited with B

Tags: github

Can anyone explain why a commit in GitHub would display the following information : [`'Contributor-A' committed with 'Contributor-B' on 15 Feb`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imRHU.jpg).

Does it mean that 'Contributor-A' is the author (who does not have the push access to the master) and 'Contributor-B' is the committer/maintainer?

Then why isn't there a PR created for merging this commit? Or does it mean that there was a closed PR about this commit, but the maintainer did not merge it via web interface but performed rebase or cherry-picking to include it?

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you include a sample of what you are seeing and how you think something is wrong?

Comment: Sorry I did not say it clearly. I did not find anything is wrong. I just don't fully understand the information on GitHub commit page. And I cannot find the answer via Google. I've added a figure to illustrate my question.

Comment: It is difficult to fully answer your question without seeing a GitHub link to the repository or the Git repo itself.

Answer (score 2):

> ...maintainer did not merge it via web interface but performed rebase or cherry-picking to include it?

I was able to get this by cherry-picking a commit from another branch and directly pushing to the current branch - [an example on GitHub](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/tree/master/tests/cherrypick).

A [Pull Request](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/) is not required to push code between branches. A Pull Request is a method that allows developers to collaborate on changes prior to merging between branches.

Comment: Many thanks for your example. I should have tried it by myself...I am aware that PR is not compulsory to push code. I just thought the workflow is a relatively strict rule that devs should follow. But now I know that this rule is kind of flexible. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sidenote: When using the checkboxes in the integrated commit interface in Xcode (7.3.2) you also get the effect of 'A' committed with 'A' on Github. So it's essentially cherry-picking under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

For sure, it happens when the pull request was merged by "Rebase and Merge" strategy via the web interface, but I'm not sure if this is the unique case.

> **Contributor-A** committed with **Contributor-B** on 15 Feb.

Contributor-A submitted the pull request and Contributor-B effectively merged it.

It might happen in other scenarios as described here: [how to apply a git patch as if the author committed to my repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15551298/how-to-apply-a-git-patch-as-if-the-author-committed-to-my-repo)